# necessity of 'which' in this sentence

Tags: grammar, relative-pronouns

> Instead, from his hub at the center of the wheel, he could choose how much attention to give them, as well as ***which*** other rim points he wanted to focus on.

> Instead, from his hub at the center of the wheel, he could choose how much attention to give them, as well as other rim points he wanted to focus on.

Is there a need for the word "which" in the example above? if so, what purpose does it serve in that phrase grammatically?

(In my opinion, the reader would still be able to understand the message conveyed by the writer even if the word **"which"** was removed.)
Please tell me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Grammatically, "which" is a determiner in the noun phrase "which other rim points [he wanted to focus on]" in which the bracketed element is a relative clause modifying "other rim points". Determinative "which" is typically selective, though if it is dropped in your example there would be little change of meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Instead, from his hub at the center of the wheel, he could choose how*
> *much attention to give them, as well as which other rim points he*
> *wanted to focus on.*

Grammatically, "which" is a determiner in the noun phrase "which other rim points [he wanted to focus on]" in which the bracketed element is a relative clause modifying "other rim points".

Determinative "which" is typically selective, though if it was dropped in your particular example there would be little change of meaning.

Answer (score 1):

> what purpose does [which] serve in that phrase grammatically?

It is difficult to say because the excerpt from the source text does not include the antecedent of the pronoun "them." It seems that "them" refers back to an earlier occurance of a set of rim points.

If that is correct, then "which" serves at least one important  purpose in this context.

In the sentence that includes "which," there are at least three discrete sets of rim points:

1. the set that was mentioned before the pronoun "them" (the text of the excerpt does not include the first time these rim points are mentioned) and that are a set separate from the set mentioned after the pronoun "them" (a set described as a set of "*other* rim points");

then this set of "other" rim points can be separated into two subsets:

2. a subset of rim points which he wanted to focus on; and
3. a subset of rim points which he did not want to focus on.

These sets of rim points might be labeled as sets *1*, *2a*, and *2b*.

The sentence version without the word "which" does not explicitly separate the set of "other rim points" into two subsets (a set of rim points which he wanted to focus on, and a set of rim points which he did not want to focus on). In that *which*-less sentence, it is not clear whether there are any rim points (in the set of "*other* rim points") which he does not want to focus on.

Those sets of rim points might be labeled as sets *1* and *2*.